# How to make installer on Linux, Mac, and Windows?

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos, installation

I have developed a program using Java SE on Windows 7.
I build this app and it runs well on Windows.
I tried to run on Linux, so it runs but after some steps of:

- Removing OpenJDK app.
- Install Java JDK from terminal
- Run jar file from terminal.

I need to make an installer on Windows - Linux - Mac, which installs JDK package and make the program run by double clicking.

Comment: What have you searched for so far?

Comment: I don't think the average user is going to be really happy that you force a particular implementation and version of Java onto their system. It should be enough to state in the installation instructions that a particular version of Java is recommended to have installed, and point them to java.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice). It is a nifty tool for converting Jar files into runnables for different systems. There are lots of tutorials on the internet on how to use it, although it is very well labelled and I found it simple enough to use.